# Is reading a textbook and doing problems the best way to self-study game theory?

Tags: self-learning

In preparation for a research position, I'm supposed to self-study the first six chapters of Osborne Introduction to Game Theory over the next two weeks, and complete corresponding problem sets.

Is reading the book and attempting problems the most efficient way to learn this material, or should I look for online lectures or something to supplement?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are tasked to do this for the position, do it. Leave philosophical questions for retirement. Supplementing with further material, looking up lecture notes and such can' hurt, now can it.

Comment: though if you get stuck, there may be courses that use the book that offer notes.